# How to remove symbols from a column using awk

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have data like this:

```
chr1    134901  139379  -   "ENSG00000237683.5";
chr1    860260  879955  +   "ENSG00000187634.6";
chr1    861264  866445  -   "ENSG00000268179.1";
chr1    879584  894689  -   "ENSG00000188976.6";
chr1    895967  901095  +   "ENSG00000187961.9";
```

I generated by parsing a GTF file

I want to remove the `"`'s and `;`'s from column 5 using awk or sed if it possible. The result would look like this:

```
chr1    134901  139379  -   ENSG00000237683.5
chr1    860260  879955  +   ENSG00000187634.6
chr1    861264  866445  -   ENSG00000268179.1
chr1    879584  894689  -   ENSG00000188976.6
chr1    895967  901095  +   ENSG00000187961.9
```

Comment: you can also use multiple seach and replace statements in sed. sed 's/"//g; s/;//g' filename

Comment: @DigitalTrauma ya, but Dani_l already gave that solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [`gsub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html):

```
awk '{gsub(/\"|\;/,"")}1' file
chr1    134901  139379  -   ENSG00000237683.5
chr1    860260  879955  +   ENSG00000187634.6
chr1    861264  866445  -   ENSG00000268179.1
chr1    879584  894689  -   ENSG00000188976.6
chr1    895967  901095  +   ENSG00000187961.9
```

If you want to operate *only* on the fifth field and preserve any quotes or semicolons in other fields:

```
awk '{gsub(/\"|\;/,"",$5)}1' file
```

Comment: This would remove from all columns, not just 5th, no?

Comment: This is what I thought initally, but after using the code it seemed to keep all columns.

Comment: @Dani_l Yes, it can be refined to operate only on the fifth field, but that was not a requirement...

Comment: Sorry I must have not made it clear, I DO want to keep all columns. This is why it is marked as the answer.

Comment: @System updated to ensure it only operates on the fifth field.

Comment: Why not just use a character class?  `/[;"]/` is a lot more readable and simpler in my opinion than `/\"|\;/`.

Comment: @Wildcard didn't think of it, but you are right, a bracket expression would be a better/more legible solution...

Answer (score 6):

If your data is formatted exactly as shown (i.e. no other `"` or `;` in other columns that need to be preserved), then you can simply use `tr` to remove these characters:

```
tr -d '";' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Using sed to remove all instances of '";':
`sed -i 's/[";]//g' file`

To only remove from 5th column sed is probably not the best option.

Answer (score 3):

I know the original post asked for sed or awk but if you want to remove the " and ; from only the fifth column I'd use regex and php. There's probably a way to do this in AWK but I like to use the easiest tools.

```
<?php

foreach(file($argv[1]) as $line){

    $matches = array();
    preg_match('/^(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\-|\+)\s+"(\w+.\d)"\;/',$line,$matches);
    $matched_line = array_shift($matches); // remove the first element
    vprintf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",$matches);
}
```

this would output this

```
$ php /tmp/preg_replace.php /tmp/data
chr1    134901  139379  -   ENSG00000237683.5
chr1    860260  879955  +   ENSG00000187634.6
chr1    861264  866445  -   ENSG00000268179.1
chr1    879584  894689  -   ENSG00000188976.6
chr1    895967  901095  +   ENSG00000187961.9
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this satisfies the "easiest tools" criteria; just the amont of typing alone...

Comment: I prefer php to awk and sed and this is the only answer that actually does what the original post requested by removing " and ; from only the fifth column. Give me that point back.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, and no, my edited answer also only operates on the fifth field (and has other advantages besides brevity)...

Comment: ah, ok. I didn't see the edited version. $5 is definitely less typing. For me PHP code is easier so I provided a solution I thought would help someone.

Comment: Fair enough, it is always good to see solutions using different approaches...

Answer (score 3):

A sed solution that makes sure we're only fiddling around with the fifth column:

```
sed -E 's/^(([^ ]+ +){4})"([^"]+)";$/\1\3/' infile
chr1    134901  139379  -   ENSG00000237683.5
chr1    860260  879955  +   ENSG00000187634.6
chr1    861264  866445  -   ENSG00000268179.1
chr1    879584  894689  -   ENSG00000188976.6
chr1    895967  901095  +   ENSG00000187961.9
```

This works also without ERE (`-E`, or `-r` for some older sed), but requires a lot more backslashes. The `+`-quantifier is ERE-only according to the POSIX spec<sup>1</sup> and can be replaced by `{1,}` (or `\{1,\}` for BRE).

In case the columns aren't space-separated, the spaces can be replaced by the `[:blank:]` POSIX character class to also match tabs.

The regex in detail:

```
^               # Anchored at start of line
(               # Capture group 1 for first 4 columns
    (           # Capture group 2 for repeat count
        [^ ]+   # 1 or more non-spaces
         +      # 1 or more spaces
    ){4}        # 4 times "word plus spaces" (columns)
)               # End capture group 1
"               # Column 5 starts with double quote (not captured)
(               # Capture group 3 for column 5
    [^"]+       # One or more non-quote characters
)               # End capture group 3
";              # Quote and semicolon at end of column 5
$               # Anchored at end of line
```

---

<sup>1</sup> GNU sed, as an extension, allows `\+` to be used in BRE as well.

Answer (score 2):

If every line has fixed length (as in the example) than

```
cut -c1-28,30-46 INFILE
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can use [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) to achieve what you want. Here is the code

```
[root@localhost]# cat ./test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
        echo ${line//[\";]/}
done < sample.txt
```

and this is the output

```
[root@localhost]# ./test.sh
chr1 134901 139379 - ENSG00000237683.5
chr1 860260 879955 + ENSG00000187634.6
chr1 861264 866445 - ENSG00000268179.1
chr1 879584 894689 - ENSG00000188976.6
chr1 895967 901095 + ENSG00000187961.9
```